# IVT Theorem Calculator in Python

Tags: python, calculus

I am having a problem.

```
def f(x):
    function = input("Enter yoru Function: ")
    return function


a = -1
b = 2
a_Applied = f(a)
b_Applied = f(b)

if a_Applied < 0 and b_Applied > 0:
    print "IVT Applies."
elif a_Applied > 0 and b_Applied < 0:
    print "IVT Applies"
else:
    print "IVT Does Not Apply"
```

This is my current code. I am trying to let the user make a function in line 2. However this breaks the program because it is a string. How do I get it to not be a string, and instead for it to be able to take a function.

Ex.

User inputs "2*x + 1"
In a perfect world the program then runs 2(a) +1 and 2(b) + 1 and then compares them using the if statement. Because the input is a string ti doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because this one asks for a parameter-ized function instead of evaluation of a math expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lambda` expression and `eval` function. Like this.

```
def read_user_function():
    function_str = input("Enter your Function: ")
    return lambda x: eval(function_str, { 'x' : x })
```

Call user function by

```
f = read_user_function()
print(f(2))
```

Here is a demo https://repl.it/ITuU/2.

**Explanation**

The function above, `read_user_function` returns a lambda expression, basically a function, that will evaluate the user's input with the variable, sort of like a parameter, `x` set to the `x` value that is passed to the lambda expression. This can get confusing if your new to this sort of thing but just think of `read_user_function` as returning an anonymous function that accepts a single argument and its body equals `eval(function_str, { 'x' : x })`

**Warning**

This is a quick and dirty solution to evaluating mathematical expression. The function would execute any valid python code and not only mathematical expression. This may be dangerous if your application is sensitive - you wouldn't want the user executing custom code.

Comment: Hi EyuelIDK. Thank you so much for the answer! I do have another problem with this, and maybe you can help me out. Firstly, could you please explain what your answer does? Secondly, when I run the program with this code it does not prompt the user for a function. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: Just saw your new edits, however when I do this and put in an example function of "2x" I get this error:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Will/PycharmProjects/IVT Calculator/IVT Calculator.py", line 5, in <module>
    f = read_user_function()
  File "C:/Users/Will/PycharmProjects/IVT Calculator/IVT Calculator.py", line 2, in read_user_function
    function_str = input("Enter your Function: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    2x
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: It expects a python expression. Note that this is not the best solution, it is just a quick solution because the the function will evaluate any valid python code.

Comment: Even with 2 * x, x is not defined is the error. I attempted to define x before running the function however it returns this error: TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object

Comment: I've put a demo up, you can run it and see. It works for me.

Comment: That's so weird! It's telling me x is not defined when i run it. EDIT: Found the problem - I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do is very hard (in general). You'd need to define rigorous semantics for all your supported operations (for example, is power `^` or is it `**` like you'd do in python?).

The `sympy` library has a start on this for you. If you assume your input is a polynomial, for example:

```
import sympy    
y = sympy.Poly("x^2 + 2*x + 1") 
print(y(3))
# outputs 16
```

`sympy` also has the advantage that it will accept "python-like" input as well:

```
import sympy
y = sympy.Poly("x**2 + 2*x + 1")
print(y(3))
```

Note that `sympy` is not limited to polynomials, just included them here as an example because polynomials are relatively simple.

Comment: Hi mwm - I have installed sympy and have put `import sympy` at the top of my code, however PYCharm will not detect it. Do you know the fix?

Comment: How did you install it? `pip install sympy`? That should put it in the right spot for Pycharm to pick it up. If you're using something like Anaconda, you need to adjust your project's interpreter to point to Anaconda.

Comment: I'm using Windows, not Linux. Haha.

Comment: You can `pip install` on windows (cmd or powershell, for example). I'm on windows too...

Comment: Start -> type "cmd" -> prompt opens -> execute "pip install sympy" in shell. Hopefully that does the trick. Installing without `pip` can be error prone.